# Why is this a covering map of Riemann manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry

Can you tell me, wh the following is true: If $f: M \rightarrow N$ is a smooth map between complete and connected Riemannian manifolds which fulfills $f^{*}(g_n)=g_M$ for the metrics $g_m$ and $g_N$ on $M$ and $N$, then it is a covering map?

Comment: Since the metric pulls-back, the Levi-Cevita connection pulls back as well, so the image of a geodesic is a geodesic.  Use exponential coordinates in $N$, by design it lifts to exponential coordinates based at the fibres of points $f^{-1}(p)$ for $p \in N$.  That's the idea.  Basically the unique path-lifting property of a covering space is guaranteed via the exponential map.

Comment: I think you need an additional hypothesis or 2.  For example, if $M =\mathbb{R}$ and $N = \mathbb{R}^2$ with their standard metrics and $f$ is the natural inclusion, then $f$ pulls back the metrics, but is not a covering.  Perhaps some kind of surjectivity condition is all that is needed.  My copy of Do Carmo is at school - I know he proves something similar to this in the spirit of Ryan's comment, but I don't recall all the hypothesis.

Comment: @Jason: I think you just need the manifolds have the same dimension and the map is a submersion.

Comment: If the dimensions are equal and the metric pulls back to the metric, don't we have automagically a submersion?

Comment: The passage I was thinking of in Do Carmo is not quite as I remembered.  They hypothesis is simply that $\|d_p f v\| \geq \|v\|$ for all vectors $v$ (much weaker than $f^*(g_n) = g_m$), but he also assumes $f$ is a local diffeomorphism, which is quite strong.  On the other hand, being a local diffeomorphism follows from $f^*(g_n) = g_m$ together with the fact that, say, $M$ and $N$ have the same dimension (as Mariano suggested).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is true, even without the assumption that N is complete.  See Lemma 11.6 in my book "Riemannian Manifolds: An Introduction to Curvature."